# Type signature for curried function

Tags: dart

How can I add a type signature for a curried function in Dart?

In this example, I want to add a `Function(int) => Function(int) => String type` signature to the function `f` here:

```
void main() {
  Function f = (int a) => (int b) => "$a + $b";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use syntax like `ReturnType Function(ParamType paramName)` as type for a function.

In your case:

```
void main() {
  String Function(int) Function(int) f = (int a) => (int b) => "$a + $b";
}
```

You can also use a `typedef` if you need this type at several place.

```
typedef MyFunction = String Function(int) Function(int);
void main() {
  MyFunction f = (int a) => (int b) => "$a + $b";
}
```

Note that you can omit the types in your lambda because with typed functions inference knows that parameters are ints.

```
typedef MyFunction = String Function(int) Function(int);
void main() {
  String Function(int) Function(int) f1 = (a) => (b) => "$a + $b";
  MyFunction f2 = (a) => (b) => "$a + $b";
}
```